# Response success but FCM Notification Not received on device

Tags: c#, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
{
 "multicast_id":5269694491339255869,
 "success":1,
 "failure":0,
 "canonical_ids":0,
 "results":[{
             "message_id":"0:1512971008200317%c522639e66d6cf16"
           }]
}
```

var applicationID = "AAAAIzHIwq4:xxxxxxxxxxxxx"; // applicationID means google Api key 
                        var SENDER_ID = "1511xxxxxxxxxxxx"; // SENDER_ID is nothing but your ProjectID (from API Console- google code)
                        var value = txtmessage.Text.Trim();

```
                    WebRequest tRequest;

                    tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
                    tRequest.Method = "post";
                    tRequest.ContentType = " application/json";
                    tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", applicationID));
                    tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", SENDER_ID));
                    string postData = "{\"collapse_key\":\"score_update\",\"time_to_live\":0,\"delay_while_idle\":false,\"data\": { \"message\" : " + "\"" + value + "\",\"registration_ids\":[\"" + Reg_Id + "\"]}";
                    Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
                    tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
                    Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream();
                    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                    dataStream.Close();
                    WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse();
                    dataStream = tResponse.GetResponseStream();
                    StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                    String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();
                    tReader.Close();
                    dataStream.Close();
                    tResponse.Close();
```

Above is fcm server response
but Notification not received on device.
Application is on idle state.
Sending the notification from c# code

Comment: What device are you referring to? Please show us the code involved.

Comment: One plus 3T on stok Rom and YU Yureka on custom rom both having same issue. Many devices facing same issues

Comment: Is `postData` meant to contain JSON? _If so, I wouldn't recommend using string concatenation to build JSON payloads._

Comment: Problem is FCM notification not receiving if app is idle for few days

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having similar problems